# Remove NULLS from dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am unable to remove the nulls from a dynamic query result.

Here's an example of what would be in #t3 table:

```
BornDate    |  ClickDate    |  Clicks
10/23/2014  |  11/19/2014   |  25
10/23/2014  |  11/18/2014   |  6
10/23/2014  |  11/20/2014   |  5
10/23/2014  |  11/22/2014   |  17
10/23/2014  |  11/23/2014   |  11
10/24/2014  |  11/19/2014   |  1
10/24/2014  |  11/18/2014   |  6
10/24/2014  |  11/20/2014   |  3
10/24/2014  |  11/21/2014   |  3
10/24/2014  |  11/23/2014   |  2
```

So, my question is, how do I remove the `NULL` values when I run the following query?

Here's my query

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(ClickDate)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ClickDate FROM #t3 ) AS ClickDate order by ClickDate

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  'SELECT BornDate, ' + @ColumnName + '  
    FROM #t3 
    PIVOT (SUM(Clicks) 
          FOR ClickDate IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable order by 1, 2'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

The result of the query is:

```
| BORNDATE   | 2014-11-18 | 2014-11-19 | 2014-11-20 | 2014-11-21 | 2014-11-22 | 2014-11-23|
|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-----------|
| 2014-10-23 |          6 |         25 |          5 |     (null) |         17 |        11 |
| 2014-10-24 |          6 |          1 |          3 |          3 |     (null) |         2 |
```

You see the NULLS on the 10/23/2014 line for the column on 11/21/2014...and again for the 10/24/2014 row in the column for 11/22/2014.  I want to replace these nulls.

Comment: Are you getting a NULL in your `clicks` column and you wish to display a zero instead? try to use `SUM(COALESCE(Clicks,0))`

Comment: @laylarenee I believe -lee is asking for the result set not to have any nulls.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using the `@ColumnName` for both the list of values to become new columns and the final select list, you need to create a separate list of column names that will replace the `null` with a zero - similar to `isnull(yourcol, 0) as yourcol`.

I typically use `FOR XML` and `STUFF` to concatenate my column names, so you can use:

```
--Get null replacements of the PIVOT Column 
select @NullName = STUFF((SELECT ', IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(ClickDate)+', 0) as '+QUOTENAME(ClickDate)
                    from #t3
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

This creates a second second of column names that will be used for the final select list. Then your PIVOT code will be:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @NullName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(ClickDate)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ClickDate FROM #t3 ) AS ClickDate order by ClickDate

--Get null replacements of the PIVOT Column 
select @NullName = STUFF((SELECT ', IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(ClickDate)+', 0) as '+QUOTENAME(ClickDate)
                    from #t3
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  'SELECT BornDate, ' + @NullName + '  
    FROM #t3 
    PIVOT (SUM(Clicks) 
          FOR ClickDate IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable order by 1, 2'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1c06/221). This gives a final result:

```
| BORNDATE   | 2014-11-18 | 2014-11-19 | 2014-11-20 | 2014-11-21 | 2014-11-22 | 2014-11-23|
|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-----------|
| 2014-10-23 |          6 |         25 |          5 |          0 |         17 |        11 |
| 2014-10-24 |          6 |          1 |          3 |          3 |          0 |         2 |
```

Answer (score 3):

To replace nulls with zero:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnNameSelect AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(ClickDate)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ClickDate FROM t3 ) AS ClickDate order by ClickDate

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column with isnull for zero values
SELECT @ColumnNameSelect= ISNULL(@ColumnNameSelect + ',','') 
       + 'isnull(' + QUOTENAME(ClickDate) + ',0) as ' + QUOTENAME(ClickDate)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ClickDate FROM t3 ) AS ClickDate order by ClickDate


--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  'SELECT BornDate, ' + @ColumnNameSelect + '  
    FROM t3 
    PIVOT (SUM(Clicks) 
          FOR ClickDate IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable order by 1, 2'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15c7a/5)